# Python requests get content from streaminghttpresponse

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a django API that stream a response using protobuff messages

```
def retrieve(self, request, event_date=None, notification=None):
   ...
   return StreamingHttpResponse(self.generator(leaseEvents, 2000), content_type='application/protobuf')

def generator(self, qs, BATCH_SIZE=2000):
    pages = Paginator(qs.order_by("event_date").values_list('reference', 'event_date', 'event_msg'), BATCH_SIZE)
    for i in pages.page_range:
        p = pages.get_page(i)
        for event in p:
            # filling protobuf object
            yield lease_event.SerializeToString()
```

Using Postman to query the API works well.

My goal is to get the result with the python requests module, but I only get an empty response.

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    print(r)
    print(r.headers.get('content-type'))
    print(r.headers)
    print(r.content)
    print(len(r.content))
    print(r.elapsed.total_seconds())
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        print("hi")
        if line:  # filter out keep-alive new lines
            print(line)
```

Here is the result

```
<Response [200]>
application/protobuf
{'Date': 'Tue, 14 Apr 2020 09:05:45 GMT', 'Server': 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf', 'Vary': 'Accept, Cookie', 'Allow': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIG
IN', 'Content-Length': '0'}
b''
0
0.675784
```

I think requests assume the `content-length` is 0, even if I'm using `StreamingHttpResponse` which doesn't provide `content-length`.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance :)